# Read Random Memory Locations with Golang

Tags: go, memory-address, memory-access

Good evening,

I've been trying to build a golang application which scans values in memory but am struggling trying to understand how to address specific memory locations. I know that when accessing memory within the application you can use `*variablename` to deference and get the address location, but how would I provide an address location and print the value to the screen or grab the next allocated object of any size from RAM and print it's value?

Thanks in advance for any help you may be willing to share

Comment: Do you want to read *your process* memory, I hope, and not *system* memory, right? Because the operating system usually disallows processes to read outside their memory space.

Comment: Also, the quality of the answer may be OS-dependent. Is your question relative to any OS, and do you want to operate within go's limits, or are you available to consider OS-dependent solutions?

Comment: @AkiRoss — this is a macintosh application reading another processes memory. I am open to Mac and Windows focused solutions though

Comment: Normally, a non-root process cannot read the memory of another process due to OS' memory protection mechanisms (edit: and even root processes can't do it very easily). So, you probably need some external agent allowing you to read the other process' memory, such as the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem in Linux (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux) - you may want to search for similar mechanisms under mac, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: **BOUNTY EDIT:** We are talking about Windows-OS!

Comment: Have you tried https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how much useful this will be, but here is a sample code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var i int = 1
    fmt.Println("Address : ", &i, " Value : ", i)

    var address *int
    address = &i // getting the starting address

    loc := (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(address))
    p := unsafe.Pointer(loc)

    // verification - it should print 1
    var val int = *((* int)(p))
    fmt.Println("Location : ", loc, " Val :",val) // it does print !!

    // lets print 1000 bytes starting from address of variable i
    // first memory location contains 1 as expected
    printValueAtMemoryLocation(loc, 1000)

    // now lets test for some arbitrary memory location
    // not so random ! wanted to reduce the diff value also any arbitrary memory location you can't read !!
    memoryToReach := 842350500000
    loc = changeToInputLocation(loc, memoryToReach)
    fmt.Println("Loc is now at : ", loc)
    // lets print 1000 bytes starting from the memory location "memoryToReach"
    printValueAtMemoryLocation(loc, 1000)

}

func changeToInputLocation(location uintptr, locationToreach int) uintptr {
    var diff,i int
    diff = locationToreach - int(location)

    fmt.Println("We need to travel ", diff, " memory locations !")

    if diff < 0 {
        i= diff * -1
        for i > 0 {
            location--
            i--
        }
    } else {
        i= diff
        for i > 0 {
            location++
            i--
        }
    }
    return location
}

func printValueAtMemoryLocation(location uintptr, next int) {
    var v byte
    p := unsafe.Pointer(location)
    fmt.Println("\n")
    for i:=1; i<next; i++ {
        p = unsafe.Pointer(location)
        v = *((*byte)(p))
        fmt.Print(v," ")
        //fmt.Println("Loc : ", loc, " --- Val : ", v)
        location++
    }
    fmt.Println("\n")
}
```

Using "unsafe" package is not a good idea, also you can not read any arbitrary location I believe.

For me when I tried some other random locations where, most probably, I didn't have read access, it threw me error like this:

```
unexpected fault address 0xc41ff8f780
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0xc41ff8f780 pc=0x1093ec0]
```

But hopefully, it can be of some value to you.

Comment: Great answer and if helps! Thank you!

Comment: I am glad that it helped :)

Comment: This does not do what the O.P. wanted. I have no idea why it was accepted as correct, let alone upvoted at least ten times. Someone recently asked the same question on the go-nuts mailing list and referred to this question. They didn't understand why this solution did not do what they wante. Which was the same thing that @kkirsche wanted. The answer is this solution doesn't do what either of those individuals want to do. You have to used specialized debugging APIs, such as `ptrace()`, to read the virtual memory of other processes.